# Unable to display tree view in parameterized Java Mapping in SAP PI 7.5

Tags: java, sap-pi, javax.xml, sap-xi

I am working on `parameterized` java mapping. While testing in Operation Mapping it gives us error:

> Unable to display tree view; Error when parsing an XML document (Premature end of file.)

And the trace log shows:

> Resource not found: META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory

We faced the same issue for `DocumentFactory` as well but we wrote the following code and it resolved the `documentfactory` issue.

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = new com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl();
```

But we are still facing the same error for `TransformerFactory`. Please find below the entire code and please let me know changes to be done.

**XmlNFe_To_Mail :**

```
    package nfeb2b.company;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
//import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
//import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
 
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
//import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
//import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

//import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.AbstractTrace;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.AbstractTransformation;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformationException;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationInput;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationOutput;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.lookup.Channel;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.lookup.LookupService;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.lookup.Payload;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.lookup.RfcAccessor;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.lookup.XmlPayload;


public  class XmlNFe_To_Mail extends AbstractTransformation {
    private String prefixoSubject = new String();
    private String emailFrom = new String();
    private String prefixoDocumento = new String();
    private String frase = new String();
    private String gap = "\n\r";
    //private AbstractTrace trace = null;
    //private Map map = null;
    public String BSSystem;
    public String ComChannel;
    public String Emails;
    private final String NFE_EMPRESA = "NFE Company ";
    private final String NFe = "NFE";   
    private final String NFe_Mail = "nfe@company.com";
    public String email="";
    public String idNFe = "";
    public String numeroNF = "";
    
    
    
    public void transform(TransformationInput arg0, TransformationOutput arg1) throws StreamTransformationException {
        
        BSSystem= arg0.getInputParameters().getString("BS_NAME");
        ComChannel=arg0.getInputParameters().getString("CHANNEL_NAME");
        Emails=arg0.getInputParameters().getString("EMAIL");
        
        getTrace().addInfo("Business System: " +BSSystem+ " Channel:" +ComChannel+" Emails:"+Emails);
        
        this.execute(arg0.getInputPayload().getInputStream(), arg1.getOutputPayload().getOutputStream());   
    }
    public void execute(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws StreamTransformationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getTrace().addInfo("Before Try Block");
                 try
                 { 
                     getTrace().addInfo("Inside Try Block");
                     configParamEmail();
                     getTrace().addInfo("After ConfigParamEmail");
                     BufferedReader inpxml = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                     StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                     String line = "";

                     String quebra = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                    while ((line = inpxml.readLine()) != null) {
                        line.replaceAll("\r\n", "");
                        line.replaceAll(quebra, "");
                        line.replaceAll(" />", "/>");
                        line.replaceAll(" />", "/>");
                        line.replaceAll(" />", "/>");
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }
                     getTrace().addInfo("After WhileLoop");
                    String inptxml = buffer.toString();
                    inptxml = inptxml.replace("\r\n", "");
                    inptxml = inptxml.replaceAll(quebra, "");
                    inptxml = inptxml.replaceAll(" />", "/>");
                    inptxml = inptxml.replaceAll(" />", "/>");
                    inptxml = inptxml.replaceAll(" />", "/>");
                    
                    
                
                    idNFe = inptxml.substring(inptxml.indexOf("<chNFe>") + 7, inptxml.indexOf("</chNFe>"));
                    numeroNF = idNFe.substring(25, 34);
                     getTrace().addInfo("idNFE value:"+idNFe);
                     getTrace().addInfo("numeroNF value:"+numeroNF);
                    
                    String pdf = "";
                     getTrace().addInfo("Before LookUp");
                     getTrace().addInfo("Going to GetValue");
                    this.getValue(idNFe);            
                     
                    // monta XML de saida XiMail
                     getTrace().addInfo("Before DocumentBuilderFactory");
                     
                     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = new com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl();

                     
                    DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document docout = db.newDocument();
                    Element root = docout.createElement("ns0:Mail");
                    root.setAttribute("xmlns:ns0", "http://sap.com/xi/XI/Mail/30");
                    //BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "utf-8"));
                    docout.appendChild(root);
                    
                    getTrace().addInfo("Root value: "+root);
                    
                    
                    Element subject = docout.createElement("Subject");
                    root.appendChild(subject);
                    Text subjectText = docout.createTextNode(getPrefixoSubject() + numeroNF);
                    getTrace().addInfo("SubjectText: "+subjectText);// Cria                                                                         // campo
                    subject.appendChild(subjectText);

                    // Cria elemento From
                    Element from = docout.createElement("From");
                    root.appendChild(from);
                    Text fromText = docout.createTextNode(getEmailFrom()); // Cria valor                                                        // campo
                    from.appendChild(fromText);
                    getTrace().addInfo("FromText: "+fromText);
                    
                    
                    if (email.length() > 0) {
                        email += ";";
                    } else {
                        email = this.getEmaillist();
                    }
                    getTrace().addInfo("Email: "+email);
                    // Cria elemento To
                    
                    Element to = docout.createElement("To");
                    root.appendChild(to);
                    Text toText = docout.createTextNode(email);
                    getTrace().addInfo("toText: "+toText);// Cria valor campo
                    to.appendChild(toText);

                    // Cria elemento Content Type
                    Element contentType = docout.createElement("Content_Type");
                    root.appendChild(contentType);
                    // Text contentTypeText = docout.createTextNode("application/xml");
                    // //Cria valor campo
                    Text contentTypeText = docout.createTextNode("multipart/mixed;boundary=--AaZz"); // Cria
                                                                                                        // valor
                    getTrace().addInfo("contentTypeText: "+contentTypeText);                                                                                // campo
                    contentType.appendChild(contentTypeText);

                    // Criando o corpo de texto do e-mail e o anexo
                    BodyText texto = new BodyText(idNFe, getFrase(), inptxml, pdf);
                    // Cria elemento Content
                    Element content = docout.createElement("Content");
                    root.appendChild(content);
                    Text contentText = null;

                    // substituir a sua empresa
                    if ("NFE: ".equalsIgnoreCase(getPrefixoSubject())) {
                        contentText = docout.createTextNode(texto.getnfeText());
                    }
                    // substituir a sua empresa
                    else if ("NFE CANCELADA : ".equalsIgnoreCase(getPrefixoSubject())) {
                        contentText = docout.createTextNode(texto.getCnfeText());
                    } 
                    else if ("COE FMC: ".equalsIgnoreCase(getPrefixoSubject())) {
                        contentText = docout.createTextNode(texto.getcceText());
                    } 
                    getTrace().addInfo("contentText: "+contentText);    
                content.appendChild(contentText);

                
                
                /*Transformer trns = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                DOMSource targetMsg = new DOMSource(docout);
                StreamResult stRslt = new StreamResult(out);
                trns.transform(targetMsg, stRslt);*/
                
                TransformerFactory tf=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                   Transformer transform=tf.newTransformer();
                transform.transform(new DOMSource(docout), new StreamResult(out));
                    
                    
                 
             }
                 catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        
                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        
                    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        
                    } catch (TransformerException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                // Exception Handling } 
                 }
             }
    
    
    public String getGap() {
        return gap;
    }

    public void setGap(String gap) {
        this.gap = gap;
    }

    public String getFrase() {
        return frase;
    }

    public void setFrase(String frase) {
        this.frase = frase;
    }
    
    
    public String getBSystem(){
        return BSSystem;
    }
    
    
    public String getEmaillist(){
        return Emails;
    }
    
    public String getCChannel() {
        return ComChannel;
    }
    
    
    
    public String getPrefixoSubject() {
        return prefixoSubject;
    }

    public void setPrefixoSubject(String prefixoSubject) {
        this.prefixoSubject = prefixoSubject;
    }

    public String getEmailFrom() {
        return emailFrom;
    }

    public void setEmailFrom(String emailFrom) {
        this.emailFrom = emailFrom;
    }

    
    public String getPrefixoDocumento() {
        return prefixoDocumento;
    }

    public void setPrefixoDocumento(String prefixoDocumento) {
        this.prefixoDocumento = prefixoDocumento;
    }
    
    public String getValue(String idNFe){
        String contentnew;
        
        String rfcxml=  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+"<ns0:OTC_NFE_MAIL_OUTPUT xmlns:ns0=\"urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions\">"+"<I_ACCESS_KEY>"
                + idNFe + "</I_ACCESS_KEY><I_CANCEL/></ns0:OTC_NFE_MAIL_OUTPUT>";
        getTrace().addInfo("RFCXML:"+rfcxml);
        RfcAccessor accessor = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outRFC = null;
        try{
            getTrace().addInfo("Went inside GetValue");
            Channel channel  = LookupService.getChannel(getBSystem(),getCChannel());
             accessor  = LookupService.getRfcAccessor(channel);
            getTrace().addInfo("After LookUp");
            
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rfcxml.getBytes());
            XmlPayload payload  = LookupService.getXmlPayload(inputStream);
            Payload rfcOutPayload  = accessor.call(payload);
            InputStream inputs = rfcOutPayload.getContent();
             outRFC = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] bufferbyte = new byte[1024];
            for (int read = inputs.read(bufferbyte); read > 0; read = inputs.read(bufferbyte)) {
            outRFC.write(bufferbyte, 0, read);
            }
            contentnew = outRFC.toString();
            getTrace().addInfo("Content"+contentnew);
            int Start_Index , End_Index ;
            Start_Index = outRFC.toString().indexOf("<E_EMAIL>") + 9; 
            getTrace().addInfo("StartIndex"+Start_Index);
            End_Index= outRFC.toString().indexOf("</E_EMAIL>"); 
            
            getTrace().addInfo("EndIndex"+End_Index);
            email = outRFC.toString().substring(Start_Index,End_Index);
            getTrace().addInfo("Email"+email);
            return email;
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)

        {

        throw new RuntimeException("Error message"+e);

        }
        
    
        
    }

    private void configParamEmail() {
        setEmailFrom(NFe_Mail);
        setPrefixoDocumento(NFe);
        setPrefixoSubject(NFE_EMPRESA);
        
    }

    
    


    /*public void setParameter(Map arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }*/


    

}
```

**BodyText.java:**

```
package nfeb2b.company;

import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.AbstractTransformation;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformationException;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationInput;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationOutput;

public class BodyText extends AbstractTransformation  {

    public String nfeText = new String();
    public String cnfeText = new String();
    public String cceText = new String();
    public String content = new String();
    public String chaveNFe = new String();
    public String frase = new String();
    public String xmlString = new String();
    public final String gap = "\n\r";
    public String numeroNFe = new String();
    public String dataNFe = new String();
    public String serieNFe = new String();
    public String pdf = new String();
    public String pdfattachment_nfe= "NF-e  - ";
    public String pdfattachment_cnfe="NF-e Cancelada - ";
    public String pdfattachment_ccfe="CC-e - ";
    
    

    // public String sefazNFe = new String();
    public BodyText()
    {
        
    }

    public BodyText(String chaveNFe, String frase, String xmlString, String pdf) {
        this.chaveNFe = chaveNFe;
        this.frase = frase;
        this.xmlString = xmlString;
        this.pdf = pdf;
        this.numeroNFe = chaveNFe.substring(25, 34);
        this.dataNFe = chaveNFe.substring(4, 6) + "/20"
                + chaveNFe.substring(2, 4);
        this.serieNFe = chaveNFe.substring(22, 25);
        // this.sefazNFe = chaveNFe.substring(0,2);
        pdfattachment_nfe = pdfattachment_nfe + chaveNFe + ".xml";
        pdfattachment_cnfe=pdfattachment_cnfe + chaveNFe + ".xml";
        pdfattachment_ccfe=pdfattachment_ccfe + chaveNFe + ".xml";
    }

    public String getGap() {
        return gap;
    }

    public String getnfeText() {
    
        nfeText = "Prezado cliente, " + getGap()
                + "Segue  "
                + getGap() + getGap() + "Número da NF-e: "
                + numeroNFe + getGap() + "Serie: " + serieNFe + getGap()
                + "Data emissão (MM/AAAA): " + dataNFe + getGap() + getGap()
                + "Atenciosamente," + getGap() + getGap() + "FMC";

        
        content = "----AaZz\r\n"+ "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" +"\r\n" + "Content-Disposition: inline\r\n\r\n" + nfeText + "\r\n----AaZz\r\n" + "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=" + pdfattachment_nfe + "\r\n"

        + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" +pdfattachment_nfe + "\r\n\r\n"  + "\r\n" +"\r\n";

       

        return content;
    }

    public String getCnfeText() {
    
        cnfeText = "Prezado cliente, "
                + getGap()
                + "Segue."
                + getGap() + getGap() + "Número da NF-e: "
                + numeroNFe + getGap() + "Série: " + serieNFe + getGap()
                + "Data emissão (MM/AAAA): " + dataNFe + getGap() + getGap()
                + "Atenciosamente," + getGap() + getGap() + "FMC";

        
        content = "----AaZz\r\n"+ "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" +"\r\n" + "Content-Disposition: inline\r\n\r\n" + nfeText + "\r\n----AaZz\r\n" + "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=" + pdfattachment_nfe + "\r\n"

        + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" +pdfattachment_nfe + "\r\n\r\n" + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" + "\r\n" +"\r\n";

        
        return content;
    }

    public String getcceText() {
        cceText = "Prezado cliente, "
                + getGap()
                + "Segue ."
                + getGap() + getGap()
                + "Número da NF-e que recebeu correção eletrônica: "
                + numeroNFe + getGap() + "Série: " + serieNFe + getGap()
                + "Data emissão (MM/AAAA): " + dataNFe + getGap() + getGap()
                + "Atenciosamente," + getGap() + getGap() + "FMC";
    
        
        
        content = "----AaZz\r\n"+ "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" +"\r\n" + "Content-Disposition: inline\r\n\r\n" + nfeText + "\r\n----AaZz\r\n" + "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=" + pdfattachment_nfe + "\r\n"

        + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" +pdfattachment_nfe + "\r\n\r\n" + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" + "\r\n" +"\r\n";

        return content;
        
    }

    @Override
    public void transform(TransformationInput in, TransformationOutput out) throws StreamTransformationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
}
```

Please find below trace **log:**

> ```
> Resource not found: META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
> com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.MappingClassNotFoundException: META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.transformerfactory
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.InternalMappingFinder.getInputStream(InternalMappingFinder.java:125)
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.InternalMappingFinder.readFile(InternalMappingFinder.java:63)
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.MappingLoader.findResources(MappingLoader.java:354)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1241)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:1237)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:348)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
>     at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:279)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:275)
>     at javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:251)
>     at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:106)
>     at nfeb2b.fmc.XmlNFe_To_Mail.execute(XmlNFe_To_Mail.java:195)
>     at nfeb2b.fmc.XmlNFe_To_Mail.transform(XmlNFe_To_Mail.java:69)
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.JavaMapping.executeStep(JavaMapping.java:112)
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.Mapping.execute(Mapping.java:60)
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.SequenceMapping.executeStep(SequenceMapping.java:40)
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.Mapping.execute(Mapping.java:60)
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.MappingHandler.map(MappingHandler.java:87)
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.execution.MappingHandler.map(MappingHandler.java:54)
>     at com.sap.aii.ibrep.server.mapping.rt.MappingHandlerAdapter.run(MappingHandlerAdapter.java:139)
>     at com.sap.aii.ibrep.server.mapping.exec.ExecuteIfMapCommand.execute(ExecuteIfMapCommand.java:33)
>     at com.sap.aii.ib.server.mapping.exec.CommandManager.execute(CommandManager.java:43)
>     at com.sap.aii.ibrep.server.mapping.ServerMapService.execute(ServerMapService.java:40)
> ```

Please let me know what changes need to be done. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed in the SAP Note `1392205 - JAXP Factory classes cannot be instantiated`?

Comment: Hi Jagger.. I checked the SAP note which you suggested. I don't think it's applicable in our case. I have googled about this issue and this transformer factory issue is still faced by many.

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace in the question then?

Answer (score 1):

Check note 2669221 - Java mapping: Resource not found: META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

Apply these two lines via note 2669221:

```
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

Alternatively add these two lines before calling the factories:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```